# minus the quantity value in the database by $_POST in yii

Tags: database, post, yii

I have a table called Apparatus and there is a column there called "quantity",
I have another table called Transaction where you can select the apparatus id and reserve a quantity

how can i minus the quantity in the transaction from the quantity in apparatus? I'm getting undefined index: id error...
here is a code in my controller:

```
if (isset($_POST['Transaction']))
    {
        $transaction->attributes = $_POST['Transaction'];
                $transaction->save();

    $apparatus = Apparatus::model()->findByPk($_POST['id']);
    $apparatus->quantity = $apparatus->quantity - ($_POST['quantity']);
    $apparatus->save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before doing arithematic operation, check whether the index `id` is present.

I am sure, your `$_POST` variables does not hold `id` as index.

So, i suggest to do the following:

```
if(Yii::app()->request->getPost('id') && Yii::app()->request->getPost('quantity') && Yii::app()->request->getPost('Transaction')){

    $id = (int) Yii::app()->request->getPost('id');
    $quantity = (int)  Yii::app()->request->getPost('quantity');
    $apparatus = Apparatus::model()->findByPk($id);

    if($apparatus){
        $apparatus->quantity = $apparatus->quantity - $quantity;
        if($apparatus->validate()){
            $apparatus->save();
        }else{
            // Log 
            var_dump($apparatus->errors);
        }
    }

}
```

Alternatively, you can dump {`var_dump($_POST)`} the post variables to see whether the $_POST contains id as index.

Comment: my error is gone but wont subtract the quantity still, any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked `$_POST['quantity']` in your `$_POST` array ?

Comment: the $_post quantity in the transaction is working fine, it's suppose to subtract the quantity it got from the transaction to the quantity in the apparatus. perhaps my $apparatus->quantity = $apparatus->quantity - ($_POST['quantity']); is wrong?

Comment: I didn't use your codes exactly but I got the idea from it, thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did: (controller)

```
if (isset($_POST['Transaction']))
    {
        $transaction->attributes = $_POST['Transaction'];
                $transaction->save();
    $id=$transaction->apparatus_id=($transaction['apparatus_id']);
    $quantity=$transaction->quantity=($transaction['quantity']);
    $apparatus = Apparatus::model()->findByPk($id);
    $apparatus->quantity = $apparatus->quantity - $quantity;
    $apparatus->save();
    }
```